# Bind HTML code string on Angular 2 template

Tags: javascript, angular

I have HTML code on Component variable like below :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `Hi <div [innerHTML]="name"></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
   styles: [`
    .highlight {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  `],
})
export class AppComponent {
name :string ="dude ! <input type='text'/>";
}
```

It shows the output like "Hi dude !" But no text box there.How can I display the text box bind using component variable ?

Comment: What does it show in the browser if you inspect it?

Comment: there is no text box ctrl code on inspecting in the browser, simply "Hi <div> dude </div>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is not secure. So, rendering input elements is disallowed by default. You need to use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to allow it:

```
constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.name = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml( this.name);
}
```

See the [plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/RCWso8Jkfvv23r3s1vZd?p=preview) that illustrates this.